# trouble with picturebox (vb)

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

*sorry if there is a lack of information I'm new to vb and writing code in general*

I am trying to make a picture box display a different picture depending on a variable (in this case lives) but I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

I would assume something like

```
    If (lives = whatever) Then
       Picturebox.Image = (yourImage)
    End If
```

If the image is in your resources then

```
    If (lives = whatever) Then
       Picturebox.Image = My.Resources.yourImageName
    End If
```

Comment: ive figured out my problem now 
the problem was that i had it in a sub that only updated when i lost a life
so my problem wasnt with the picture box it was that the sub was not updating (if that makes sense) (but thanks for the help anyway)